# Incrementing the array value within an array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

So my end result will be this (the end result will have 48 entries):

```
$theArray=array(
$theArray1,
$theArray2,
$theArray3,
$theArray4,
$theArray5,
$theArray6
);
```

I have tried a few things but I think this is the closest, but I'm still not there yet, any help appreciated.

```
$i = 0;
while ($i <= 48){
  $theArray[]=${"theArray".$i.","}
  $i++
 }
$theArray[]=${"theArray".$i};
```

Comment: Uh, what is the question?

Comment: Why don't you have `$theArray1`, `$theArray2`, etc defined as array values in the first place, so no numbers or hacky conversions necessary? Where are these values coming from?

Comment: Are you looking for this, Is your desire output like: [https://3v4l.org/5khJe](https://3v4l.org/5khJe)

Comment: Yes, but rather the entries in the arrays rather than a string

Comment: Perhaps I should add $theArray1, $theArray2.. etc are arrays

Answer (score 2):

You missed ; at the end of line:

```
$i = 0;
while ($i <= 48){
  $theArray[]=${"theArray".$i.","}; // missed ; here
  $i++; // missed ; here
 }
$theArray[]=${"theArray".$i};
```

Comment: Sorry that was in haste, but it still doesn't work how I intended it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the function compact for create an array containing variables. Try to read the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php

And here are some example http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_compact.asp

Comment: Yes perhaps this is the answer, but I'm struggling to incorporate it into a loop, I'll keep trying though.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple as below:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$theArray = array();
while ($i <= 48){
  array_push($theArray, '$theArray'.$i);
  $i++;
 }
echo '$arr = array('.implode(',', $theArray).');';
?>
```

Just run this on your end. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks I think this is nearly it, but rather than it output each array as a string I need it to be the actual array. The above outputs the following: Array ( [0] => $theArray0 [1] => $theArray1 [2] => $theArray2 [3] => $theArray3 ) rather than the values within $theArray0 etc..